# Can I use html.action within a foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a situation where I'd like to use html.action within a foreach within a view like this.

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Sections)
    {
       <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-offset-2">
           <div>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
               @Html.Action("Edit", "Section", new { id = item.SectionId })
           </div>
       </div>
    }
</div>
```

However, if I run this I get an "httpserverutility.execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete" error.  All of my controller actions are async, so I'm thinking I did something that just isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may be trying to render asynchronous partial views from within a view. This was quite a controversial issue from my research. It was [Issue 601](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601) on ASP.NET issues. I believe it has been resolved in the newer versions of ASP.NET MVC. Refer to the ASP.NET MVC documentation [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/partial.html) and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Yes  - this.  I'd considered that async wouldn't work on the rendered views, but I had a vague memory that it wouldn't work.  It did.  So while this might be not exactly what you were suggesting - good job.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you want to accomplish (i.e. Do you want to display the result of the Action? Do you want a link that points to it? etc.)

**Rendering the Action**

If you want to render the result of the defined action, you should consider using the [`Html.RenderAction()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction(v=vs.118).aspx) method :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
@Html.RenderAction("Edit", "Section", new { id = item.SectionId })
```

**Providing a Link**

If you wanted to render a link that points to the specific Action, which seems more likely in this scenario, you should consider using the [`Html.ActionLink()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) method :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
@Html.Action("Edit", "Edit", "Section", new { id = item.SectionId }, null)
```

Answer (score -1):

this could help you ,

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
         <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PGId)
         </td>
         <td>
              @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PGId})
         </td>
    </tr>
}
```